# Unable to obtain the id of the element using v-if

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to VueJS. I am developing an application using VueJS and Bootstrap. There is a div which I wish to render based on a condition.

I have been trying to use `v-if` on the div so that once the condition is true, the data property is set to true and the div gets displayed.

My code looks like this:

```js
export default {
    
    data(){
      
      return {

        detailsSectionOpen: false
        
      }
   },
   
   methods:{
   
    showDetails() {
        if(this.detailsSectionOpen === false){
           this.detailsSectionOpen = true;
        }
        const detailsSection = document.getElementById("details");
        const showSection = document.getElementById("show");
        detailsSection.classList.add("col-xl-3");
        showSection.classList.add("col-xl-9", "col-md-6");
        showSection.classList.remove("col-xl-12", "col-md-6");
      },
   
   }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="content" style="padding-top: 3px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6" id="show" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">

        <div class="container-fluid">

          <ol class="breadcrumb" id="topButtons" style="display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 0rem 1rem;background-color: transparent;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 13px; color: #424242; 
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; 
                font-size: 18px; 
                font-weight: normal; 
                font-style: normal; 
                text-decoration: none; 
                text-align: left;">Files</li> 
            <li class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn">
                <i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc">
                </i>
              </button>
            </li> 
            <li class="pull-right">
              <button v-if="gridView === false" @click="changeView" class="btn">
                <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
              </button>
              <button v-if="gridView === true" @click="changeView" class="btn">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ul">
                </i>
              </button>
            </li> 
            
          </ol>

          <!-- Line break -->
          <hr class="breadcrumb-hr">

        </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div style="width: 280px; height: 30px; margin-left: 15px; ">
          <p style="color: #424242; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; text-align: left;">Recent</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Recently used files section begins here -->
        <div class="row" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
          
          <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6" v-for="(file,index) in recentFiles">
            <stats-card>
              <div slot="header" class="header-rectangle" @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.menu.open">
                <img :src="file.source" style=" height: 50px; margin-top: 50px">
              </div>
              <div slot="footer" class="footer-rectangle" @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.menu.open" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-xl-9"  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="file-name-style">
                        <span>{{file.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-size-style" >
                      <span>{{file.size}} MB</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-3" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; margin-top:">
                    <div v-show="!file.shared" style="float: right; padding: 0px 5px 5px 0px; margin-right: 10px;">
                      <i class='fas fa-users' id="image"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </stats-card>
          </div>

          <vue-context ref="menu">
            <ul style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; ">
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fa fa-file' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Preview</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Share</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="fa fa-copy" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Copy/Move</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='far fa-star' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Add to Starred</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-cloud-download-alt' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Download</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Rename</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class='fas fa-tag' id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Tags</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Delete</span></li>
              <li class="context-menu-item" @click="onClick($event.target.innerText)"><i class="far fa-chart-bar" id="context-menu-icon"></i><span class="context-menu-span">Access Stats</span></li>
            </ul>
          </vue-context>

        </div>

        <!-- Folder section begins here -->
        <div v-if="gridView === true" style="width: 280px; height: 30px; margin-left: 15px;">
          <p style="color: #424242; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; text-align: left;">Folders</p>
        </div>

        <div v-if="gridView === true" class="row seven-cols" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
          <div class="col-md-1" id="no-padding" v-for="(folder,index) in folders">
            <stats-card>
              <div slot="header" :data-key="index" class="folder-rectangle" @click="folderSelected=index" :class="{'folder-selected':folderSelected==index}">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xl-3" style="padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;">
                    <div class="clearfix" v-if="folder.shared" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px;">
                      <i class="material-icons" id="folder-image">&#xe2c9;</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px;" v-else>
                      <i class="material-icons" id="folder-image">folder</i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-9" style="padding-left: 7px;padding-right: 7px;padding-top: 7px;padding-bottom: 7px;">
                    
                      <div class="file-name-style" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
                        <span>{{folder.name}}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="file-size-style" style="padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 5px;">
                        <span>{{folder.numFiles}} files</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              
            </stats-card>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Files section begins here -->
        <div v-if="gridView === true" style="width: 280px; height: 30px; margin-left: 15px;">
          <p style="color: #424242; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; text-align: left;">Files</p>
        </div>

        <div v-if="gridView === true" class="row" style="padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">

          <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
            <stats-card>
              <div slot="header" class="header-rectangle">
                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/136/136526.png" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 50px">
              </div>
              <div slot="footer" class="footer-rectangle" style="display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;">
                <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12"  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="file-name-style">
                        <span>File Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-size-style" >
                      <span>1 MB</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </stats-card>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
            <stats-card>
              <div slot="header" class="header-rectangle">
                <i class="far fa-file-image" style=" height: 50px; margin-top: 50px; color:#4CAF50; font-size: 40px;"></i>
              </div>
              <div slot="footer" class="footer-rectangle" style="display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;">
                <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12"  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="file-name-style">
                        <span>File Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-size-style" >
                      <span>1 MB</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </stats-card>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
            <stats-card>
              <div slot="header" class="header-rectangle">
                <img src="http://www.dap.asn.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pdfLogo.png" style=" height: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">
              </div>
              <div slot="footer" class="footer-rectangle" style="display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;">
                <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12"  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="file-name-style">
                        <span>File Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-size-style" >
                      <span>1 MB</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </stats-card>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
            <stats-card>
              <div slot="header" class="header-rectangle">
                <img src="https://www.cleverducks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Excel-Icon.png" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 50px">
              </div>
              <div slot="footer" class="footer-rectangle" style="display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;">
                <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-xl-12"  style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="file-name-style">
                        <span>File Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-size-style" >
                      <span>1 MB</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </stats-card>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <!-- List View section begins here -->
        <list-view :gridView="gridView" :folders="folders">

        </list-view>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- File Details section begins here -->
    <div v-if="detailsSectionOpen" id="details" ref="detailsSection">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ol class="breadcrumb" id="topButtons" style="display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 0rem 1rem;background-color: transparent;margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <li class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn" @click="closeDetailsSection">
                <i class="fa fa-close">
                </i>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Line break -->
          <hr class="breadcrumb-hr-details">
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div style="width: 280px; height: 30px;">
            <p style="color: #424242;width: 239px;height: 30px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 16px; 
                      font-weight: bold; 
                      font-style: normal; 
                      text-decoration: none; 
                      text-align: left;">Details</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: 0 auto" >
                <i class="fas fa-folder" style="font-size: 100px; color: #878D99"></i>
              </div>
              <div style="max-width: 100%;">
                <ul style="list-style: none;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 60px;padding-bottom: 60px;" class="details-ul">
                  <li>Shared with: ~ 15 people</li>
                  <li>Name: Folder Name</li>
                  <li>Type: Folder</li>
                  <li>Files: 20</li>
                  <li>Location: Home</li>
                  <li>Owner: John</li>
                  <li>Created: March 10, 2018</li>
                  <li>Opened: March 10, 2018, 7 PM by Jenny</li>
                  <li>Modified: March 10, 2018, by me</li>
                  <li>Downloaded: March 10, 2018, by John </li>
                  <li>Retention Policy:  None</li>
                  <li>Tags: Add</li>
                  <li>Description: Add</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: 0 auto" >
                <button class="plus-circle-btn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

I am able to see the div being rendered on the DOM when the method showDetails() is called.

But, when I try getting the element by its ID, the result is null. So, `document.getElementById('details')` returns null.

I think it has something to do with the reactivity in Vue and how v-if works. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Part of your problem may be that there's no element with the ID of `show`.

Comment: You should also look into the `ref` attribute. Put a `ref="foo"` on an element and you can access it's DOM element via `this.$refs.foo`.

Comment: `<div v-if="detailsSectionOpen"...>` (remove the `this.`) ought to show the div when your model "detailsSectionOpen" becomes true. Also _"once the condition is true, the data property is set to true"_ - The div & v-if reacts to the change in the property, the property doesn't react to the div.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried using refs. It doesn't work

Comment: See my first comment, and @StephenP's. You've got multiple issues. `ref`s will probably work when you resolve the others, and it's cleaner and more Vue-friendly.

Comment: @StephenP I removed the this from the detailsSectionOpen. I still get null when trying to access the element

Comment: @ceejayoz I have an element with id = "show"

Comment: Not in the code you've shared with us.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have edited the code. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenP Did you get a chance to check the code?

Answer (score 2):

`v-if` adds/removes an element from the DOM. You can't show or hide something that doesn't exist in the DOM.

Trying to hide or show another DOM element based on a different element's `v-if` doesn't make any sense as you could simply add another `v-if="condition"` and it would work the same way.

If you really can't add another check to the DOM then you should **Watch the same data element in VUE that the if is watching...**

Do this by adding a class as that's better for toggles since ID's are only supposed to be used once per page. You can add this class anywhere in the DOM based on the Vue state.

```
<div v-if="visibleCheck">
  This element will be visible if visibleCheck = true
</div>

<div id="anotherElement" v-bind:class="visibleCheck ? 'isVisble' : 'notVisible'">
 If visibleCheck = true this div will have a class .isVisible
 If visibleCheck = false/null this div will have a class .notVisible
</div>
```

Then do something with those classes:

```
.isVisible {
 display:block;
}
.notVisible {
 display:none;
}
```

**The whole point of Vue is NOT to watch the DOM for changes but to base the DOM changes on the data**

Using your example:

```
<div id="whatever" v-bind:class="detailsSectionOpen ? 'col-xl-9' : 'col-xl-12'">
   stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$nextTick`, it will be called after the component re-render:

```
showDetails() {
     if(this.detailsSectionOpen === false){
        this.detailsSectionOpen = true;
     }
     this.$nextTick(() => {
       const detailsSection = document.getElementById("details");
       const showSection = document.getElementById("show");
       detailsSection.classList.add("col-xl-3");
       showSection.classList.add("col-xl-9", "col-md-6");
       showSection.classList.remove("col-xl-12", "col-md-6");
     })
   }
}
```